# Why does this usage of std::move and std::list with a custom view type cause an infinite recursion?

Tags: c++, stl, c++20, move-semantics, std-ranges

I was reading §5.1.7.2 of Rainer Grimm's book *C++20: Get the Details* about defining one's own view type when I decided to modify the provided code sample to see if it would work with a `std::list`. The code ultimately looks like this:

```cpp
#include <concepts>
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <ranges>
#include <vector>

template <std::ranges::input_range Range>
  requires std::ranges::view<Range>
class ContainerView : public std::ranges::view_interface<ContainerView<Range>> {
  private:
  std::ranges::iterator_t<Range> begin_ {};
  std::ranges::sentinel_t<Range> end_ {};
  Range range_ {};

  public:
  constexpr ContainerView() = default;

  constexpr ContainerView(Range r)
      : begin_(std::begin(r))
      , end_(std::end(r))
      , range_(std::move(r))
  {
  }

  constexpr auto begin() const { return begin_; }
  constexpr auto end() const { return end_; }
};

int main()
{
  std::list my_list { 1, 2, 3 };
  auto my_container_view { ContainerView(std::views::all(my_list)) };

  for (auto const& c : my_container_view)
    std::cout << c << '\n';
}
```

The program compiles successfully with x86-64 clang++ v17.0.1 and the flags `-std=c++20 -fsanitize=undefined -fsanitize=address -Wall -Wextra -Werror`, and, when run, it prints the numbers 1, 2 and 3 and exits gracefully as expected.

However, out of curiosity, when I altered the `main` function to wrap `my_list` in a call to `std::move` when passing it to `std::views::all`, the program appears to get stuck in an infinite recursion repeatedly printing the elements of the list.

```cpp
int main()
{
  std::list my_list { 1, 2, 3 };
  auto my_container_view { ContainerView(std::views::all(std::move(my_list))) };

  for (auto const& c : my_container_view)
    std::cout << c << '\n';
}
```

What I found strange is that when I simply exchange the `std::list` for a `std::vector` instead and keep the rest of the code untouched, the program prints each element once and exits gracefully:

```cpp
int main()
{
  std::vector my_vec { 1, 2, 3 };
  auto my_container_view { ContainerView(std::views::all(std::move(my_vec))) };

  for (auto const& c : my_container_view)
    std::cout << c << '\n';
}
```

I also do not get the aberrant behavior when I remove the indirection of the `ContainerView` type and iterate over the `std::list` directly:

```cpp
int main()
{
  std::list my_list { 1, 2, 3 };

  for (auto const& c : std::move(my_list))
    std::cout << c << '\n';
}
```

Given that each variation of the code compiles and yields no compile time constraint errors, is there a semantic constraint that I am violating with the use of `std::move` and `std::list` in combination with the custom view type that would cause the apparent undefined behavior?

Comment: Moving the range invalidates the iterators. You get UB. `begin_ { std::begin(range_) }; end_ { std::end(range_) };` - accessing the not yet constructed range. It's weird if you don't get compiler warnings.

Comment: Please forgive me if I have misunderstood something, but I think that, given the fact that the class fields are initialized in order of their declaration, the initialization of `range_` should only occur after initialization of `begin_` and `end_` and therefore be valid. Edit: Never mind, thanks so much for that comment. I see what you mean now. However, even if I change the code to have  `begin_` and `end_` simply default-initialized, I seem to get the same problematic behavior.

Comment: @273K, I have updated the code to default-initialize `begin_` and `end_` as per the issue you pointed out.

Comment: @273K: Presumably they could change the declaration order (in both class and initializers) to put `begin_` and `end_` *after* the `range_`. Initializers do have defined order, do they not?

Comment: @ShadowRanger Yes, you are right, changing the declaration order would fix the direct member initializion. The `ContainerView(Range r)` still leads to UB, it stores iterators to a moved object. It's already a success story in the self-answer.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`std::list` needs to use a sentinel node for its end iterator (it needs to support `--`). There are two ways to do it:

- a sentinel node embedded in the list itself. libstdc++ and libc++ do this.
- a dynamically allocated sentinel node. MSVC does this.

In the first case, when you move a list, iterators to elements become iterators of the new list, but the end iterator still points to the original list. So in your code, if `r` wasn't empty then `begin_` is pointing the first element in `range_` after the move, but `end_` is still pointing into the soon-to-be-destroyed `r`. So when the loop tries to increment `begin_` until it reaches `end_`...well, it will never do that and you get an infinite loop. (It is convenient for the sentinel node's next pointer to point to `*begin()`, which is why this looks like it's iterating the list multiple times.)

This is only a problem when you move the list because `views::all` is by-reference on lvalues, so in that case everything is dealing with the same `list` object.

Side note: It's pretty tricky to store an iterator (or sentinel) and the range it points to at the same time if the containing class can be copied or moved. The default memberwise copy/move will not work - you'd need to do the equivalent of [*`non-propagating-cache`*](https://eel.is/c++draft/range.nonprop.cache) for the iterator.

Comment: Just to clarify my understanding, the problem occurs when moving the `std::list` into the `std::views::all` because it will implicitly create what is equivalent to a `std::ranges::owning_view` whereas without the move it would implicitly create a `std::ranges::ref_view`, correct?

Answer (score 2):

Following the advice of @273K, ensuring that `begin_` and `end_` are initialized in the constructor body following the move of the `Range` `r` into `range_` in the member initializer list eliminates the undefined behavior.

```cpp
#include <concepts>
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <ranges>
#include <vector>

template <std::ranges::input_range Range>
  requires std::ranges::view<Range>
class ContainerView : public std::ranges::view_interface<ContainerView<Range>> {
  private:
  std::ranges::iterator_t<Range> begin_ {};
  std::ranges::sentinel_t<Range> end_ {};
  Range range_ {};

  public:
  constexpr ContainerView() = default;

  constexpr ContainerView(Range r)
      : range_(std::move(r))
  {
    begin_ = std::begin(range_);
    end_ = std::end(range_);
  }

  constexpr auto begin() const { return begin_; }
  constexpr auto end() const { return end_; }
};

int main()
{
  std::list my_list { 1, 2, 3 };
  auto my_container_view { ContainerView(std::views::all(std::move(my_list))) };

  for (auto const& c : my_container_view)
    std::cout << c << '\n';
}
```